# How can I fetch Distinct Value as well as last record using JOIN Query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

table 1

```
|id | name |

|1 | Test |

|2 | Hello|

|3 | Hii |
```

table 2

```
|id | related_id | date | time

|1 | 1 | 2014-09-11 | 12.56.25

|2 | 2 | 2014-09-11 | 12.56.25

|3 | 2 | 2014-09-12 | 11.56.25

|4 | 2 | 2014-09-12 | 12.56.31 (Last record)
```

OUTPUT

```
|id | name | date | time

|1 | test | 2014-09-11 | 12.56.25

|2 | Hello | 2014-09-12 | 12.56.31 (This is the last record from table 2)

|3 | Hii | - | -
```

SO in output table, Id=2 is last record of table 2 where relative id=2 ... and I also want all records from table 1.

So Which kind of Join Query I can use?

Comment: What does your query look like? It could be as simple as `ORDER BY someColum DESC`

Comment: Table 1

|id | name |
|-----------
|1  | Test |
|2  | Hello|
|3  | Hii  |
------------

Table 2
------------------------------------
|id | name | related_id | Comments |
|-----------------------------------
|1  | Test |     1      |  Example |
|2  | Hello|     2      | Example2 |
|3  | Hello|     2      | Example3 |
|4  | Hello|     2      | Example3 |
------------------------------------

Output
|id | name | Comments  |
|-----------------------
|1  | Test | Example   |
|2  | Hello| Example3  |
|3  | Hii  |      -    |


so I want last record of table 2 where related id = 2..

Comment: In SQL Server Cross apply is there which can achieve this thing, but I don't know what is equivalent in MYSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using self join for table2 to get the last row for each `related_id` group and use left join with inner select with your table1

```
select a.*,
d.`date`,
d.`time`
from table1 a
left join (
    select b.* 
    from table2 b
    inner join (
                select 
                max(id) id ,
                related_id 
                from table2 
                group by related_id ) c
      on(b.id=c.id and b.related_id = c.related_id)
  ) d
on(a.id = d.related_id)
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0325f/8)

Another way would be use `substring_index` and `group_concat` with order by

```
select a.*,
substring_index(group_concat(b.`date` order by b.id desc),',',1) `date`,
substring_index(group_concat(b.`time` order by b.id desc),',',1) `time`
from table1 a
left join table2 b
on(a.id = b.related_id)
group by a.id
```

[`Demo 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0325f/10)